# How to install ac-R mode in emacs?

Tags: emacs, libraries

I have recently added the file `ac-R.el` to `/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp`, along with `(require 'ac-R)` to `~/.emacs`

Now, when I open emacs with --debug-init, I get the error

```
    Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable ac-modes)
  add-to-list(ac-modes ess-mode)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*<2>> nil "/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/ac-R.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 7191
  load-with-code-conversion("/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/ac-R.el" "/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/ac-R.el" nil t)
  require(ac-R)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/dlebauer/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 3548
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/dlebauer/.emacs" "/home/dlebauer/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" t t)
  #[nil "\205\264
```

and when clicking on `load-with-code-conversion`, it says

> Can't find library
>   /usr/share/emacs/23.1.50/lisp/international/mule.el

even though I have installed mule via synaptic (I am using Ubuntu 10.04)

How can I get the mule library in the right place?

Comment: your problem is not missing mule, but that ac-R.el is a HTML file and not a Lisp file. Make sure you have saved the correct file there. :-)

Comment: @mihi thanks; I retrieved the file with `wget http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ac-R.el`  but now I see that `http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/ac-R.el` is the correct link

Comment: @mihi I have changed the error message to the one that I get when using the Lisp file ...